# facebook home/api response strange data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm confused about the behavior of Facebook graph APIs of my simple app. AppID: 650346681742538.

1) Open Facebook graph explorer tool. Call me/home?limit=100

2) See the returned feeds. Ex: we have 2 feeds f1 and f2 now.

3) Wait 5-10 minutes. Call me/home?limit=100 again.It updates 2 new feeds f3, f4 (f3, f4 will be marked as Star icon in some applications because it is new feeds ).

Now we have 4 feeds.

4) I close web browser.

5) Wait 10-15 minutes, open Facebook graph explorer again.

6) Call me/home?limit=100.The return feeds are f1, f2 only.I think it should display f1, f2, f3, f4 at least.

7) Wait 5-10'. Continue to call me/home?limit=100. It returns f1, f2, f3, f4 and some new feeds.

**Please help me understand how me/home api work 
If there was a bug or NOT.**

**additional information**

I have used only **limit** as parameter of me/home **if there are any useful params please let me know.**

+Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly related to a bug that Facebook is investigating.  See here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/670090673137505/